# Titanium hyperloop module and TiShadow

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, tishadow, appcelerator-hyperloop

Has anyone tried using the new Titanium Hyperloop module (in beta currently) in an app that is compiled and distributed via TiShadow app? Since TiShadow app isn't Alloy, I'm not sure if Hyperloop module will work with TiShadow, which would be a problem because a Titanium app using Hyperloop cannot be deployed and distributed via TiShadow any longer.